# Python socket transmitting on correct interface but with wrong source address

Tags: python, sockets, ip-address, multicast, transmission

I have a multicast system with multiple network interfaces.  Packets transmitted using the socket I created are being sent out the correct interface, but the packet's source address is incorrect.  The source address should match the interface that was used to transmit the packet over an isolated network, but it's using the source address from the interface on the private network (which ultimately connects to the internet).

What do I need to change about my socket configuration, so that transmitted packets are sent with the isolated network interface's IP address as the source address?

```
import socket

src_ip = '172.17.0.1'   # isolated network interface IP address which should be source address but isn't
dst_ip = '225.17.0.18'  # destination IP address
port = 30000
msg = bytes([0x11, 0x22, 0x33, 0x44, 0x55, 0x66, 0x77, 0x88, 0x88, 0xAA, 0xBB, 0xCC, 0xDD ])

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM, socket.IPPROTO_UDP)
sock.connect((dst_ip, port))
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_IP, socket.IP_MULTICAST_IF, socket.inet_aton(src_ip))
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_IP, socket.IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, socket.inet_aton(dst_ip) + socket.inet_aton(src_ip))
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

sock.sendall(msg)
```

The packet gets transmitted as expected, except for the source address.  Any thoughts?  I'm using Python 3.6.  I know it's old but it's what they're using here.

Comment: Use `sock.bind()` to set the source address of the socket.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks.  Calling `sock.bind((src_ip, 0))`, before calling `sock.connect()` seems to have fixed the problem.

Comment: @Barmar make that an answer. BTW, the question has basically nothing to do with Python- that just happens to be which language you're using

Comment: Shouldn't that be `socket.IPPROTO_IP` instead of `socket.SOL_IP`?  Probably why `IP_MULTICAST_IF` isn't setting the source interface.  UDP is connectionless so skip `connect` and use `.sendto()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't bind the socket to a specific address, the network stack chooses the source address arbitrarily, and it doesn't have to be the same as the address of the interface it sends from. If you want a specific source address, call `sock.bind()`.

```
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM, socket.IPPROTO_UDP)
sock.bind((src_ip, 0))
sock.connect((dst_ip, port))
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_IP, socket.IP_MULTICAST_IF, socket.inet_aton(src_ip))
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_IP, socket.IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, socket.inet_aton(dst_ip) + socket.inet_aton(src_ip))
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
```

Specifying port 0 in `bind()` allows the OS to select an unused source port.

Comment: I get an `OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument` on the call to `sock.bind()` when I run your example.  However, if I place the `sock.bind()` call before `sock.connect()`, it works.

Comment: I didn't notice the connect call

Answer (score 0):

The level specified with option IP_MULTICAST_IF and IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP should be IPPROTO_IP, not SOL_IP.  Also, UDP is connectionless.  `bind` is used to receive, but `connect` is not needed.

Receiver using my system to listen on both my network interface and the localhost interface:

```
import socket

mgrp = '224.3.29.71'
server = '', 5000
interfaces = '127.0.0.1', '192.168.1.3'

with socket.socket(type=socket.SOCK_DGRAM) as s:
    s.bind(server)
    for interface in interfaces:
        mreq = socket.inet_aton(mgrp) + socket.inet_aton(interface)
        s.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, mreq)
    while True:
        data, addr = s.recvfrom(1024)
        print(f'{addr}: {data}')
```

Sender using IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP to send on each interface:

```
import socket

msg = b'hello, world!'
mgrp = ('224.3.29.71', 5000)
interfaces = '192.168.1.3', '127.0.0.1'

with socket.socket(type=socket.SOCK_DGRAM) as s:
    ttl = 1
    s.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_MULTICAST_TTL, bytes([ttl]))
    for interface in interfaces:
        s.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_MULTICAST_IF, socket.inet_aton(interface))
        s.sendto(msg, mgrp)
```

Run the receiver and then the sender a few times:

```
('192.168.1.3', 63854): b'hello, world!'
('127.0.0.1', 63854): b'hello, world!'
('192.168.1.3', 63855): b'hello, world!'
('127.0.0.1', 63855): b'hello, world!'
('192.168.1.3', 63856): b'hello, world!'
('127.0.0.1', 63856): b'hello, world!'
```